# API wp-json/wp/v2/pages/ returns a different result if page is specified

Tags: rest-api

When I access the page content using the following command I get back "old" data (using Powershell):

```
$indpage = Invoke-RestMethod -method get -uri "https://www.zzz.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/36816" -headers $header

"ID: ", $indpage.id,$indpage.content
ID:
36816

rendered                        protected
--------                        ---------
<p>here is updated content</...     False
```

If I access as an item in the pages collection, I get the correct content:

```
$pages = Invoke-RestMethod -method get -uri "https://www.zzz.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/" -headers $header

 "ID: ", $pages[0].id,$pages[0].content
ID: 
36816

rendered
--------
<p>updated- here is updated content-updated again</p>...
```

Note the ID number is the same, There is no "draft" copy, I have checked and the "updated" content is what shows on the site itself. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I am missing the trailing "/" on the uri. If I add that to the individual post uri, it works as designed.